# cron job groovy script logging

Tags: logging, groovy, cron

I set up a cron job to call the groovy script. In the groovy script I use "ch.qos.logback" to do the logging.

If I run the script manually, the logging works fine, but when running by the cron job, there is not output to the log file.

Has anyone seen the similar issue? Thanks ahead!

Comment: How do you call the groovy script? How do you manage the dependencies? How do you configure the logger?

Answer (score 0):

Since there are so exact error, try to see if:

1. Is cron job running as same user as the one you are running the script with.
2. The directory/file permissions affect log file generation, verify that.
3. The path when you script and when your cron jobs runs may be different and hence log file may be produced at some different place (if you are using relative path for the log file)
4. Try logging to STDOUT (console appender) and check cron's log (location depending on the OS you are using var/log/syslog or var/log/cron or whatever configured)